# Function and Cursor together and moving cursor pointer down to table rows in pl/sql?. possible?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking to display information where condition match by calling the function FULLNAME but in output i am getting only 1st row.How i can move cursor pointer depending on condition to other rows in cursor area?

```
 create or replace function FULLNAME(code in varchar2)
return varchar2 is

    cursor t1 is
    select CODE_IATA,AIRPORT from airports2017
    where CODE_IATA in ('CDG','AMS','IST','ORD','DEL') ;
    --iata_code airports2017.code_iata%type;
    --airport_name airports2017.airport%type;

begin
      for t in t1
      loop
         if code = t.code_iata then
          return t.airport;
        elsif code = 'CDG' then
          return t.airport;
        elsif code = t.code_iata then
          return t.airport;
        elsif code = t.code_iata then
          return t.airport;
        elsif code = t.code_iata then
          return t.airport;

      else
        return 'Invalid code';
      end if;
    end loop;
    --close t1;
end;
/
declare
    name1 varchar2(80);
    name2 varchar2(80);
    name3 varchar2(80);
    name4 varchar2(80);
    name5 varchar2(80);
    --cursor t2 is select code_iata,airport from airports2017;
begin

    name1 := fullname('ORD');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: ORD' ||'  '|| name1);
    name2 := fullname('CDG');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: CDG' ||'  '|| name2);
    name3 := fullname('AMS');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: AMS' ||'  '|| name3);
    name4 := fullname('IST');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: IST' ||'  '|| name4);
    name5 := fullname('DEL');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: DEL' ||'  '|| name5);

end;
/
```

I am getting this in output-  [myOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M06LS.png)

Expected output -  [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFRRg.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a very good use case for a cursor - you're just doing a simple table lookup. I'm going to use a `for` loop here because it's similar to what you have, although the loop will only run once at most. I'll put a more clear way to write it at the bottom.

```
 create or replace function FULLNAME(code in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
begin
      for t in (select AIRPORT from airports2017
                where CODE_IATA = code)
      loop
        return t.AIRPORT;
      end loop;
      return 'Invalid code';
end;
/
declare
    name1 varchar2(80);
    name2 varchar2(80);
    name3 varchar2(80);
    name4 varchar2(80);
    name5 varchar2(80);
begin

    name1 := fullname('ORD');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: ORD' ||'  '|| name1);
    name2 := fullname('CDG');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: CDG' ||'  '|| name2);
    name3 := fullname('AMS');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: AMS' ||'  '|| name3);
    name4 := fullname('IST');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: IST' ||'  '|| name4);
    name5 := fullname('DEL');
    dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: DEL' ||'  '|| name5);
end;
/
```

I often see people use single-run loops (like I did above with FULLNAME), because they prefer it to exception handling, but it can be confusing. Here's another way to write that lookup function.

```
 create or replace function FULLNAME(code in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
   v_airport airports2017.airport%TYPE;
begin
      select AIRPORT into v_airport 
        from airports2017
        where CODE_IATA = code;
      return v_airport;
exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
      return 'Invalid code';
end;
/
```

Edit: Oh, and if you're trying to do an automated loop over the airports2017 table, put the cursor in your anonymous block.

```
declare
    cursor t1 is
    select CODE_IATA,AIRPORT from airports2017
    where CODE_IATA in ('CDG','AMS','IST','ORD','DEL') ;
begin
    for t in t1
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('IATA_CODE: ' || t.code_iata ||'  '|| FULLNAME(t.code_iata));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Great!.. Got it . Thanks@kfinity